# Removing adhesive tiles and painting basement floor shows ugly gaps between the former tiles

Tags: basement, painting, cement

As you can see in the attached picture, I am removing what seem to be adhesive tiles and applying basement floor paint (plain old cement paint).

But look on the left - I guess the cement was damaged over the years? The cement floor between the tiles is a bit crumbly and weird - almost grout like. I'm toying with the idea of applying a thin coat of hydraulic cement over these borders to try to make it nice and smooth.

**Is there some better solution that is not highly invasive?** (e.g. I imagine an inch or two of self leveling cement, after removing everything in the room, might be better - but that's more than I can deal with right now).

[image]

Comment: Kinda looks to me like you haven't removed all the adhesive.  Got any pics from before you painted?